# Increment in function overwritten by +=

Tags: java, variable-assignment, increment, ternary

A method called in a ternary operator increments a variable and returns a boolean value. When the function returns false the value is reverted. I expected the variable to be 1 but am getting 0 instead. Why?

```
public class Main {
    public int a=0;//variable whose value is to be increased in function
    boolean function(){
        a++;
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        Main m=new Main();
        m.a+=(m.function()?1:0);
        System.out.println(m.a);//expected output to be 1 but got a 0 !!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be undefined behavior?

Comment: Undefined behavior is a C/C++ concept.

Comment: dont you think the return type of function must be int

Comment: The expected output should be 0.  `m.function()` always returns false, so the value that gets added on is 0... 0 + 0 = 0.

Comment: @LukePark but the function increments `a`

Comment: @holidayCoder No.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But it doesn't matter that it does.  `m.a = m.a + 1 or 0 depending on whether function is true.`

Comment: function is returning false which means it is `0` and in operation it is false so `m.function()?1:0` also return 0??

Comment: @holidayCoder `false != 0` in Java...  Ternary Operator is `(condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse)`.

Comment: @LukePark ignoring the information revealed in the answer below, what this looks like it expands to is: `a += (a++ == 1) ? 1 : 0;` (I know that the function always returns `false` but this was the only inline statement I could think of as equivalent in this situation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It looks like it does but it doesn't.

Comment: @LukePark your initial statement is still incorrect though and that is what I am pointing out. The return value of the function and the ternary operator alone have nothing to do with the end value of `m.a`. It's the fact that the `+=` operator somehow replaces the post-increment state of `a`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts My initial statement isn't wrong.  I think you are misunderstanding the order.  Replacing values, it's pretty much saying `m.a = 0 (the current value) + (potentially 1 or 0)`.

Comment: @LukePark my apologies. I misinterpreted your initial claim to ignore the fact that the function incremented `a`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No worries!

Comment: What happens if you call instead `a += function()?1:0;`? The same thing? I don't have a way to compile C# currently.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Even in C or C++ the equivalent program would not have undefined behaviour. There are sequence points enough to ensure that a well-defined order is imposed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically `m.a += (m.function() ? 1  : 0)` compiles into

```
 int t = m.a; // t=0 (bytecode GETFIELD)
 int r = m.function() ? 1  : 0; // r = 0 (INVOKEVIRTURAL and, IIRC, do a conditional jump)
 int f = t + r; // f = 0 (IADD)
 m.a = f // whatever m.a was before, now it is 0 (PUTFIELD)
```

The above behavior is all specified in [JLS 15.26.2 (JAVA SE 8 edition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Comment: Upvoted +1 for you, but -1 for the JLS being foul in this respect.

Answer (score 19):

You have two operations operating on `m.a` in one call; in `main`

```
m.a += (m.function()?1:0);
```

pushes the value of `a` on the frame, and then invokes `m.function()` (which returns `false`), thus the ternary expands to `m.a += 0;` (and the value of `m.a` from the frame is added to `0` and stored in `m.a`). Thus the value is incremented in `m.function()` (and then **reset** in `main`). Consider it this way,

```
m.a = m.a + (m.function() ? 1 : 0);
```

The value of `m.a` is determined before the evaluation of `m.function()` (thus it is a post increment operation). For the result you *expected*, you could do

```
m.a = (m.function() ? 1 : 0) + m.a;
```

Comment: Why is it evaluated this way? Can you cite the JLS sources that cover this?

Comment: So the behavior is related to stack calls?

Comment: function is returning false which means it is `0` and in operation it is false so `m.function()?1:0` also return `0`??

Comment: I was perhaps unclear, it is really unrelated to the ternary, it is because of the post increment operator being used.

Comment: A prior user answered this with the same information in less detail and people voted him down twice...  If he is still here, kudos to you, I always agreed with you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2 explains how compound assignments are evaluated @JohnKugelman.

Comment: @holidayCode : yes - `m.function() ? 1 : 0` will always return 0 because `m.function()` will always return false. The entire question is "why is the a++ in function() ignored?". The answer is that the in `main()` the value of `a` is pushed onto the stack before `function()` is called, so the modification to `a` is not noticed. IMO this is a compiler bug - the compiler should have recognized that a call to a class function could potentially modify a class variable and thus shouldn't have pushed `a` until after `function` was completed.